# Замена первых двух слов в строке

Tags: php

Как заменить в строке только первые два слова?

Например, из строки `<0></0><0></0><0></0><6>` должно получиться `<0></0><0></0><6>` (итог после замены первой `<0></0>` на пустую строку).

Comment: Что есть "слово"? Ни `<0>`, ни `</0>` у меня со словом не ассоциируются. Что конкретно надо удалять?

Comment: Надо удалить первые <0></0> тоесть это слово

Comment: как определить границы слова?

Comment: Т.е. можно смело использовать [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)? Т.е. `substr($text, 7)` вас устроит?

Comment: да работает, спасибо, с использованием strlen робит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас нестандартные границы "слова", можно воспользоваться регулярным выражением, заменив первые два "слова" на пустую подстроку

```
<?php
$str = '<0></0><0></0><0></0><6>';
echo preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', '', $str, 2);
```

Comment: Эх, давно это было, еще когда верил в регулярки, а потом не понел что это полная х. +еще очень медленная, но всеравно спасибо.

Comment: Да и то решение не верно:)